# Undefined Input Value When Checking ByClassName

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the value of an input by className using pure JavaScript. When I run similar code for and ID it works, but when I try with a class name it returns undefined. I am able to do this with jQuery but I want to achieve it with pure JavaScript to have a better understanding of the language. Thank you!

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var input1 = document.getElementsByClassName("blank1");
var submit = document.getElementsByClassName("submit");

correctAnswer = 'hello';

submit[0].addEventListener('click', checkFillIn);

function checkFillIn(){
    if ( input1[0].value === correctAnswer ){
        console.log('correct!');
    }else{
        console.log('incorrect');
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p><input id="blank1" value="" type="text"></input></p>
<a href="#" class="submit">Submit</a>
```

Comment: Code seems correct to me, can you share the error you receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add class attribute on your input element. See example below:

```
<input id="blank1" class="blank1" value="" type="text">
```

Of course, you wouldn't want to make the id same with the class attribute.

Comment: I will accept this once it lets me, I'm so mad at myself because as cliche as it sounds, I had this earlier! I forgot I had changed it to an id to test and never changed it back. That's embarrassing, as I know I can be better than this! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: That's ok. It happens. Don't be so hard to yourself. :D

Answer (score 1):

Ot returns undefined because you have an error in your syntax:

`getElementsByClassName(blank1)`

blank1 was the ID not the class

This should work:

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById("blank1");
var submit = document.getElementsByClassName("submit");

correctAnswer = 'hello';

// submit is an array getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements
submit[0].addEventListener('click', checkFillIn);

function checkFillIn(){
    if ( input1.value === correctAnswer ){
        console.log('correct!');
    }else{
        console.log('incorrect');
    }
}
```

```html
<p><input id="blank1" value="" type="text"></input></p>
<a href="#" class="submit">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is on line 1, where you get the first Element in javascript. It should be:
`var input1 = document.getElementById("blank1");`
This is because blank1 is an ID, not a class name.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `var input1 = document.getElementsByClassName("blank1");`to `var input1 = document.getElementsById("blank1");`or add  `class="blank1"`to your input .